1 When I run my pgm class I get the following error:
1 When I run my pgm class I get the following error:

Apr 22, 2024 8:45:54 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.5.Final
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Could not locate cfg.xml resource [hibernate.cfg.xml]
at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.ConfigLoader.loadConfigXmlResource(ConfigLoader.java:53)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.configure(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:254)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:260)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:246)
at com.tapacad.application.pgm.main(pgm.java:16)

Can someone help me please?
